# Status 500 error instantiating servlet class caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException ronit.hello<init>

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-code-500, nosuchmethod

I was executing a web project and it is throwing an error 500 error instatiating servlet class .
I am using tomcat 9.0.71 and using web module 4.0 .

This is the error message on the screen.

[image: This is the error page status 500]

This is the HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a hello world</h1>
<br>
<form action ="hello" method="get">
<input type="submit">click to say hello world
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the servlet class

```
package ronit;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.*;
@WebServlet("/hello")
class hello extends HttpServlet{
 static final long serialVersionUID = 35335L;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

try {
PrintWriter p = res.getWriter();

p.println("Hello World");
}catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}}
```

This is the deployment configuration in the server

[This is the servlet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biPQV.png)

[This is the console after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfgE4.png)

[This is the project explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6TP9.png)

I am using annotations instead of web.xml and deploying the file by right clicking on the project and run on server.

Comment: The only thing that I can suggest is to change the line class hello extends HttpServlet{ to class Hello extends HttpServlet{  because that is the name of the file shown in project view.  I don't know that that change will make the error go away.

Comment: Don't show [screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365). Instead show the formatted text in your question. In your case, that console screenshot only shows the last few lines of the stack trace, anyway - making it less useful.

Comment: Follow the generally accepted Java [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) - for example, class names start with an uppercase letter - so `class Hello` not `class hello` - as noted by @rickz already. This will help you to avoid some surprises and make your code more readable. (Please also consider indenting the Java and HTML in your question - again for readability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your servlet class has no public, zero argument, constructor. It needs one, otherwise Tomcat can not instantiate it--exactly as the error output is telling you.